# Is every graph with a countable amount of nodes a subgraph of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$?

Tags: graph-theory, computability

**Notation:**

- Here I'm assuming there's at most one edge between two vertices, and no edges between a vertex and itself.
- By a computable graph I mean a set $(V,E)$ where the vertex set $V$ is computable and so is the edge relation $E$.
- By the graph $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, I mean the graph that has a vertex for every element and an edge between $(a,b)$ and $(m,n)$, iff $a=m$ and $b = n \pm 1$, or $b =n$ and $a = m \pm 1$, i.e. they are either horizontally adjacent or vertically adjacent.
- By a "$G'$ is a subjraph of $G=(V,E)$", (I'm not sure if this has a name so I'm making one) I mean a graph $G'=(V', E')$ with $V' \subseteq V$, such that if $e'$ is an edge between $a$ and $b$ then there exists an edge between $a$ and $b$ in $G$ or there is a path from $a$ to $b$ that does not passes through any other vertex in $G'$. It is not required for $E'$ to have all the edges that "make sense". So this works like "removing" some vertices but keeping their edges alive by stitching them together. For example, the cyclic graph with three vertices is not a subgraph of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ but it is a subjraph of it: take $V'=\{(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)\}$ and the missing edge between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is given by the path $(0,1) \to (1,1) \to (1,0)$, since $(1,1) \not \in V'$.

---

**The questions:**

1. Is every graph with a countable amount of vertices a subjraph of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$?
2. Furthermore, is every computable graph isomorphic to a computable subjraph of $\mathbb  Z \times \mathbb Z$? If so, is the isomorphism computable too?

I know little about graph theory so I don't even know how to begin to do this.

---

**The motivation:**

I want to make a computer program that displays $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and allows the user to turn off nodes and edges (by inputting two functions $f,g:\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \{0,1\}$), and I want to claim that these are all the computable graphs.

Comment: One thing your definition of subgraph doesn't make clear: what happens if two edge-chains in $G$ cross at a point that isn't a vertex of $G'$? For instance, imagine trying to embed the complete graph on four vertices by starting with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(m,0)$, $(0,m)$, $(m,m)$, the four edges of the square, and then two edge-chains from $(0,0)$ to $(m,m)$ and $(m,0)$ to $(0,m)$; these two chains must intersect at some vertex of $G$ somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It's allowed for them to intersect like that, since their intersection $(a,b)$ is still not in the vertex set so it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>No. Any complete graph with $n\ge 3$ vertices is not a subgraph of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. In particular, the complete graph with countably infinite vertices cannot be a subgraph of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$.</strike>

Yes. See comments below.

Suppose you have a computable graph on $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$, then you can construct a program such that it halts iff $(x,y)$ is an edge of this graph. On the other hand, given a program on $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$, you can define a graph such that $(i,j)$ is an edge iff it halts on both $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$. With this construction, there should be a way to exclude a large class of possibilities using the Halting problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Despite the title, I was asking for "subjraphs", see the notation section. So the complete graph with $n$ vertices is actually a subjraph of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. The complete graph with countably infinite vertices is a subjraph too. I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly the second part about the halting problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But then isn't obvious that all the graphs are subgraphs of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ ? Just embedds the vertices to $\mathbb Z\times\{0\}$, and any two vertices that need to be connected can be connected through a path that travles outside $\mathbb Z\times \{0\}$ except at the ends.

Comment: Sometimes I make really obvious questions whose solutions fly over my head, you are completely right, a similar thing can be said about the second question. I'll mark your answer as correct. (For future reference though: the actual answer is this comment here, not the post per se).